# Swift autofill OTP is receiving to my app from other app also

Tags: ios, swift

I tried with OTP autofill in my iOS app with ***UITextContentType = .oneTimeCode***, its working perfectly, but at the same time if i get OTP from other app, my app is reading OTP of other app. Means it updated with latest OTP's irrespective of app. Is there any way to resolve this one.

*textField.textContentType = . oneTimeCode*

Comment: You didn't explain what OTP means. Also add some code that shows what you're trying to do

Comment: One time code fro secure login.

Comment: textField.textContentType = . oneTimeCode

Comment: iOS doesn't know which app an OTP message belongs too. It simply offers the OTP as a keyboard shortcut to any app the user opens that has a one time password text field

Comment: ok. thanks Paulw11